# How to store boost::hana::map inside a class?

Tags: c++, boost, constexpr, boost-hana

I want to store `boost::hana::map` inside a class so that I can write code like this inside the class:

```
if constexpr (boost::hana::contains(map_, "name"_s)){
    std::cout << map_["name"_s] << std::endl;
}
```

But I am getting an error:

> note: implicit use of 'this' pointer is only allowed within the
> evaluation of a call to a 'constexpr' member function

With `this->map_`:

> note: use of 'this' pointer is only allowed within the evaluation of a call to a 'constexpr' member function

The most interesting thing is if I write like this:

```
if (boost::hana::contains(map_, "name"_s)){
    std::cout << map_["name"_s] << std::endl;
}
```

I get an error that there is no such field (it really may not exist, that's why there was an `if constexpr`).

And yet, it works like this(WHY?!):

```
auto map = map_;
if constexpr (boost::hana::contains(map, "name"_s)){
    std::cout << map["name"_s] << std::endl;
}
```

I absolutely don't understand how it works. How is `boost::hana::map` supposed to be used in this case?

[Full example](https://godbolt.org/z/jfoEKxM8T)

[Stupid workaround](https://godbolt.org/z/Gx3scTqrb)

Comment: The hint is in the note!
Try using this explicitly:
```
if constexpr (boost::hana::contains(this->map_, "name"_s)){
    std::cout << this->map_["name"_s] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @stribor14 Ah, if only it were that easy!)
> note: use of 'this' pointer is only allowed within the evaluation of a call to a 'constexpr' member function

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. You can start with this [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rhT6sM9je).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using `this` here appears to be right out.

Since the information you are trying to access should be accessible at compile-time, one simple workaround would be to use the type of the entire expression.

```
void print_name()
{
    if constexpr (decltype(boost::hana::contains(map, "name"_s)){})
    {
        Print(map["name"_s]);
    }
}
```

Note that `hana::contains` returns an object derived from `std::integral_constant` so the contained value is `static constexpr`, and it implicitly converts to `bool`.